# scroll android programmatically in all applications

Tags: android, service, scroll, scrollview, background-service

I created a background service on android and I have two buttons which appear on the top of the screen all the time. I want to use these two buttons like scroll down and scroll up. But these two buttons should work on any kind of applications like Instagram, Facebook, Twitter and so. So, it means it should work in all applications that use scrolling.

I search a week on internet but I could not find any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not possible**, sorry. Something like this would require your **Service** to have access to the **Views** of the applications and this would be a huge security breach, because you could read values from them and so on.

You could achieve this with a custom button code broadcast (so basically your buttons would act as physical buttons on the device) but this would most probably require you to have system-level permissions and some level of cooperation with the OEMs.

Android `Activity` class has a method called `dispatchKeyEvent()`, which could let you simulate the key input (with some limitations) but this is not present in the `Service` class.

Comment: then how do apps like AnyDesk are able to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not something you can do in Android. Typically you should not be able to touch views with a background service, the point of a background service is that you do some work in it (for example upload files to your web server or get some data). You CAN send a signal from a service once you're finished doing work to tell an app that something needs to happen, however the app needs to be specifically coded to respond to this broadcasted event.

If you wanted to do this with an app that you have developed, that can be achieved by using the onReceive method of say a BroadcastReceiver, however you cannot specifically define the behaviour of other apps as this would represent a security breach in Android.